# Arch Linux in Qemu : Failed to access perfctr msr error

Tags: arch-linux, qemu, initramfs

I got the Arch Linux (march build) iso file through bittorrent lately.

I tried to run it in VM, but it only gets up to the main screen (The screen where you select what you want to do) shown below:

[image]

But when I select first option, it shows a black screen which goes nowhere. The Hardware Information option seems to work, but it's out of my intellectual capacity so I ignored it.

I then tried `qemu` with a simple `qemu-system-x86_64 ./location to file` command. It shows a slightly different image:

[image]

On selecting `x64-86` I get errors:

[image]

I am a Ubuntu user, so I don't get anything of this, but the first error seems to be:

```
failed to access perctr msr(msr coo1ooo4 is 0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the perfctr message so I won't say anything about it but the message after that ("XZ-compressed data is corrupt) is worrysome. Did you verify your ISO file with any of the checksums at https://www.archlinux.org/download/ ? The easiest way to do that would be `md5sum path-to-the-file` or `sha1sum path-...`.

Comment: @Wieland I would surely do, but the problem is I have old ISO from march. How do I get sha1sum/md5sum for it? website only provides latest ISO's sha1sum/md5sum. If you have old ISO sha1sum/md5sum, please provide it.

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/releng/releases/2014.03.01/ has checksums for the old isos.

Comment: @Wieland You were right. The ISO was tampered one. the checksums did not match. But how did I got wrong ISo even after getting it from official site's official Torrent? Should I use direct link instead?

Comment: I don't know how you got a corrupt ISO. Did you download a newer one and does it work?

Comment: @Wieland No. I am currently busy with two parallel admission processes, so I don't have time this month atleast.

Answer (score 1):

I get this message (failed to access perctr msr) on boot with a functioning Arch guest in Virtualbox.  This issue has been discussed on the Arch forum (link below) and apparently is related to a cpu feature that does not exist on the system giving the error message, but the feature is unimportant, thus the message may be ignored.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1279852

In the last post:

> 2013-07-07 09:24:35
>
> endle
>      Member
>      Registered: 2013-07-07
>      Posts: 1
>
> Re: kernel error on QEMU VM boot: Failed to access perfctr msr
>   mich41 wrote:
>
> Probably something unrelated, maybe booting without "quiet" would reveal what exactly is happening before it hangs.
>
> **Thank you! After booting without 'quiet', I found where the problem is.**